# Swift UIAlertController -> ActionSheet iPad iOS8 Crashes

Tags: iphone, ipad, swift, uiactionsheet

currently i'm running into big trouble with my ActionSheet. On iPhone it works great, but on iPad it only crashes

I create a new project with only one button

```
import UIKit

extension ViewController : UIActionSheetDelegate {

    func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, didDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

        if actionSheet.tag == 0 {
            if buttonIndex == 1 {
                // doing something for "product page"
            } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
                // doing something for "video"
            }
        }
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIActionSheetDelegate {
    @IBAction func test(sender: AnyObject) {

        let systemVersion: NSInteger = (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).integerValue
        if systemVersion < 8 {
            // iOS7:
            let action:UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Change Map Type", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Back", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Product Page", "Video")
            action.tag = 0
            action.showInView(self.view)
        } else {
            // iOS8:
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Change Map Type", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
            let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Back", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
            let button1action: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Product Page", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> () in
                // doing something for "product page"
            })
            let button2action: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Video", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> () in
                // doing something for "video"
            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(button1action)
            alertController.addAction(button2action)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

}
```

As i said on the iphone it works, but if i click the button on iPad the App crashes with

> 2014-09-25 14:54:52.784 test[9541:1970048] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has
>   presented a UIAlertController () of
>   style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of
>   a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You
>   must provide location information for this popover through the alert
>   controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a
>   sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is
>   not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in
>   the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method
>   -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00613df6 **exceptionPreprocess + 182  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x01fdaa97 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   UIKit
>
>   0x0164da37 -[UIPopoverPresentationController
>   presentationTransitionWillBegin] + 3086   3   UIKit
>
>   0x00f54f75 __71-[UIPresentationController
>   _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke + 1666  4   UIKit                               0x00f53554
>   __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 226   5   UIKit
>
>   0x00f8721b __40+[UIViewController _scheduleTransition:]_block_invoke +
>   18    6   UIKit                               0x00e4d62e
>   ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15     7   UIKit                               0x00e4d5d9 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 415  8   UIKit
>
>   0x00e4d3ee _afterCACommitHandler + 545    9   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00536fbe
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 30    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00536f00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
>   + 400     11  CoreFoundation                      0x0052c93a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0052c1ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443   13  CoreFoundation
>   0x0052bfdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   14  GraphicsServices
>   0x0438424f GSEventRunModal + 192  15  GraphicsServices
>   0x0438408c GSEventRun + 104   16  UIKit
>   0x00e23e16 UIApplicationMain + 1526   17  test
>   0x00085e9e top_level_code + 78    18  test
>   0x00085edb main + 43  19  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0273eac9 start + 1  20  ???
>   0x00000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

Project can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/s/54jqd8nsc67ll5g/test.zip?dl=0 for download and try.

Comment: that post is very similar to my answer... except the exception. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037657/swift-uiactionsheet-crashes-on-ipad

Comment: Yes but still it crashes

Comment: I will update my answer soon...

Comment: okie thanks :) just best answer here other topic ll be deleted as its quiet full with random stuff

Comment: here is the solution in my updated answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26038730/1214122

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you need to give the alert controller's `popoverPresentationController` a location so that it can position itself properly. This is easy to do -- just check to see if there's a popover controller and add the sender as the source.

If your button is a `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
    popoverController.barButtonItem = sender
}
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Otherwise:

```
if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
    popoverController.sourceView = sender
    popoverController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
}
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: with swift 1.2, it's now required to do:
 popoverController.sourceView = sender as! UIView

Comment: `popoverController.sourceRect = sender.bounds` makes ActionSheet to appear on top left corner of the iPad. Instead you can use `popoverController.sourceRect = sender.frame`

Comment: `sender.bounds` works ok for me - sourceRect is 'The rectangle in the specified view in which to anchor the popover'.  I take that to mean it is in the coordinate space of the sourceView and hence .bounds

Answer (score 11):

try this

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to present it in the centre with no arrows on iPads [**Swift 3+**]:

```
    if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
    }
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

Nate Cook is totally right however I would do it so I detect if it is iPad or iPhone.

This is for `barButtonItem`:

```
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){

            if let currentPopoverpresentioncontroller = alertController.popoverPresentationController{
                currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.barButtonItem = sender as! UIBarButtonItem
                currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.down;
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }else{
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Comment: Something like this solved my problem. I did the `.barButtonItem = sender` assignment, but instead of `permittedArrowDirections`, I used `.sourceRect = sender.accessibilityFrame`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Please Select Camera or Photo Library", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){
    actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Please Select Camera or Photo Library", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
}

actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Upload a Photo", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
    self.openPhotoLibrary()
}))
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take a Photo", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
    self.openCamera()
}))
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want show your alert in center and no arrow, I tryed this, it works on iOS 11.2

swift 4.2 version:

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController ......
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){

        if let currentPopoverpresentioncontroller = actionSheet.popoverPresentationController{
            currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.permittedArrowDirections = []
            currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.sourceRect = CGRect(x: (self.view.bounds.midX), y: (self.view.bounds.midY), width: 0, height: 0)
            currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.sourceView = self.view
            self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }else{
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Objective C version:

```
UIAlertController* actionSheet 
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    NSArray *empty;
    UIPopoverPresentationController *currentPopOverPresentationController = [actionSheet popoverPresentationController];
    currentPopOverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = empty;
    currentPopOverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds), 0, 0);
    currentPopOverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;

    [self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}else{
    [self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone uses **sender : UITapGestureRecognizer** this might be helpful.

```
@objc func popupSettings(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    .....
    if let popoverPresentationController = alert.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(origin: sender.location(in: self.view), size: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
    }
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Nate Cook's answer. If your button is a `UIBarButtonItem` it may be necessary to perform casting on `sender`.

```
if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
    popoverController.barButtonItem = sender as! UIBarButtonItem
}
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```